How to interleave rust source to assembly, like `objdump -S` does for C?
I am trying to interleave rust source code to assembly just like I was able to with objdump -S <file> on a <file> generated from C code. As per this in rust-lang forum , running objdump on a rust-generated <file> results in bogus output. cargo-objdump, as of this writing on 27SEP2024, does not support -S or any interleaving option.

cargo-show-asm can do this, when given the --rust option.
